# Let user insert text to <p> at one position

Tags: javascript, html, text

The user should be able to manipulate a `<p>`'s content by inserting some content to it.
But this should be possible at only one position, so just making the paragraph `contenteditable=true` isn't everything ...

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: have you tried any code?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Have you tried using a contenteditable ```<span>```?

Comment: no, I didn't have any ideas on how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<p ><span contenteditable="true">It is editable.</span> This is a paragraph.</p>`